# Property of Hom and the tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $Y \subset X$. I want to show that $$ Y \otimes (X/Y)^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}(X/Y,Y)$$

I was thinking of using the following mapping $y \otimes f \mapsto s \cdot f$ where $s \in Y$ and $f \in (X/Y)^*$. 
However, this seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just count dimensions, actually. Both sides are finite-dimensional of dimension $(\dim Y)(\dim X - \dim Y)$, because the dimension of $X/Y$ (and its dual) is $\dim X - \dim Y$.

Answer (score 2):

For any finite dimensional vector spaces
$$V\otimes U^*\cong\text{Hom}(U,V)$$
and yes, the map is yours; $v\otimes\phi$ maps to the linear map
$u\mapsto \phi(u)v$.